Chunks with Dynamically Imported Components code Served Over HTTP Instead of HTTPS in Next.js App
We recently updated the packages in our turborepo, which includes a Node app and a Next.js app. After deploying, we noticed that some chunks are being served via HTTP instead of HTTPS, causing mixed content errors. These chunks contain components that are dynamically imported using next/dynamic with SSR set to false. Switching the imports to standard imports resolves the issue.
I’ve tried to find any open issues related to this problem but couldn’t find anything similar. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Everything was working fine before the package update. I would appreciate any help. Below, I’ve included the versions of the main packages.
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "1.7.2",
  "next": "14.2.5",
  "next-i18next": "15.3.0",
  "next-optimized-images": "2.6.2",
  "next-pwa": "5.6.0",
  "nextjs-plugin-minify-css-classname": "0.0.5",
  "react": "18.3.1",
  "react-dom": "18.3.1",
  "react-error-boundary": "4.0.13",
  "react-redux": "9.1.2",
  "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
  "socket.io-client": "4.7.5",
  "swr": "2.2.5",
  "tailwindcss": "3.4.4",
  "webpack": "5.93.0",
  "workbox-core": "7.1.0",
  "workbox-precaching": "7.1.0",
  "workbox-recipes": "7.1.0",
  "xss": "1.0.15"
}

Thank you!

